# wp_dropdown_pages in widget form

Tags: widgets

I have a small quirk somewhere in my widget form. Upon saving the widget instance, the form refreshes with the wrong selected 'page_id' from the wp_dropdown_pages input. If I refresh the widgets page, the correct, saved page_id is selected in the dropdown. Here's the portion of code:

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    if( isset( $instance['page_id'] ) ) {
        $page_id = $instance['page_id'];
    } else {
        $page_id = 0;
    }
    ?>
    <p class="description">Select a post to display it's excerpt</p>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'id' => $this->get_field_id('page_id'),
        'name' => $this->get_field_name('page_id'),
        'selected' => $page_id
    );
    wp_dropdown_pages( $args );
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['page_id'] = ( !empty( $new_instance['page_id'] ) ) ? (int)$instance['page_id'] : '';
    return $instance;
}
```

So error_logging $page_id will output 0 when I hit save, but if I refresh, $page_id will be the correct page id I need.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why but changing the update function to the following seemed to do the trick:

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    if( isset( $new_instance['page_id'] ) ) {
        if( $new_instance == '' ) {
            $instance['page_id'] = '';
        } else if ( (int) $new_instance['page_id'] > 0 ) {
            $instance['page_id'] = (int) $new_instance['page_id'];
        }
    }
    return $instance;
}
```